SpringBoot loader.path equivalent for bootRun gradle task
The Spring Boot PropertiesLauncher supports a loader.path property (or LOADER_PATH env var) that can be used to add additional classpath items at runtime. I'm using this to load some extension-related (Java SPI) classes at runtime. This works fine from CLI & using PropertiesLauncher, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar from IDE (IntelliJ) & debugging using the bootRun gradle task right in the IDE. The bootRun task doesn't seem to support those properties.
I could continue running from CLI & PropertiesLauncher and then use remote debugging but was just looking for a way to do it more easily do it all directly from within the IDE if possible.
